# Extract Google Analytics UA code with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, web-scraping

How do you extract the Google Analytics UA code on a page with Javascript. Could this be done manipulating the `ga` function or scraping the site for the code?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "extract the code".  How is this different from normal use of GA?

Comment: I have a number of website that I need to audit. So I'd like to collect the UA code from each.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are referring to the property ID, then you can access the tracking object to get the tracking ID by calling this:

```
ga.getAll()[0].get('trackingId')
```

This returns the GA property ID ("UA-XXXXX-Y").

Comment: This is great! Any idea on how to do it with the old GA?

Comment: it is better to use the snippet with callback provided by @Jakub Kriz.

Answer (score 3):

**I have to warn you** that this way:

```
ga.getAll()[0].get('trackingId')
```

is not correct and using this is not safe. The right way is to use callback as is described here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29150831/3489362

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  // very similar to internal method like ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId');
  var clientId = tracker.get('trackingId'); 
  // now you can pass client id to your internal system
  myInternalMeasurementProtocolSetter(clientId);  
});
```