# How to connect Google Analytics Measurement Protocol (back end) with a front end session? Only via Client ID?

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I have a website with Google Analytics tracking on and I have a goal that listens to the event `EVENT1`.

If I open a private tab and go to page P1, I can see it being registered as a landing page. All good.

And I visit a second page, P2, and then send the event EVENT1 (which is connected to a goal) I will see that the landing page now gets a goal conversion. All good.

This is the view I am talking about (please note that the data in the image does match my example!):

[image]

However, if I create a new GA session, and thereby get a new client ID (let's say the ID is `CID123`), visit page P1 then P2, but my backend sends the event instead over the Measurement Protocol to Google Analytics, where I specify `cid=CID123`, then the landing page conversion does not work.

I can see the event coming into Google Analytics, and I can see the goal is increased, but for some reason, the landing page conversion status does not work.

**So my question is..**

.. how do I connect a front end GA session with anything I send over the Measurement Protocol?

Since the landing page conversion does not get updated, it seems like I am missing information in my backend hits to allow Google Analytics understand its the same session.

Is specifying the client ID `cid=` the only thing required? 
Or are there any other fields/properties/data that I need to attach to connect them two?

Comment: Are you using non-interaction on your measurement protocol hit? cause if you dont, you should ! https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters?hl=es-419#ni

Comment: Don't know if this helps, but I came here looking for connecting front-end and back-end GA but then found this SO post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769391/google-analytics-measurement-protocol-how-do-i-get-the-client-id-from-cookie-on